# Flash Uploader not Calling upload php file

Tags: php, actionscript-3, file-upload

Hello everyone
I'm trying to make a flash uploader.  The issue however that has me stumped the uploader doesn't seem to be calling the php file.  I'm watching in httpfox and its dosen't seem to be calling any file.  Yet it appears to be uploading.  It never actually uploads anything but it acts normally I don't get any errors I check the logs I don't see any issues in the logs.  I have an html uploader that works fine.  What else is there to check?!  BTW this is on a server with self assigned cert I know there are issues with that but wouldn't it complain instead of not doing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your code it is difficult to help you pinpoint the error.  I suggest reviewing this flash uploader project:

http://www.swfupload.org/project

I have successfully utilized this uploader in the past and afterwards I used it as a model for creating my own uploader.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't seem to find the uploader from this link.  Could you be a little more specific.

Comment: Also I have used some other demo flash uploaders I guess I'm wondering if the self assigned SSL bug would prevent the call altogether.

Comment: Apparently I copied you the wrong link, I meant to paste the SWFupload link now in my entry.